# Android why Parsing Datetime in a desired Format taking around 50-60 milisec?

Tags: android, parsing, datetime-format

I am trying to parse a date time in the desired format using below code

```
date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(data);
formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM''yy, HH:mm aa").format(date);
```

But the thing is for the first time parsing is taking near around `35` ms, and after that formatting is taking near around `15 ms`.

But on an average, if I am trying to parse `50, 40, 30, 20, 10` dates then it is taking around `900, 750, 600, 450, 200 ms` resp, which is also pretty much above what it should take.

Can anyone please tell me why is it taking so much time?

Is there any other way of doing this faster than the current approach?

Comment: I don't know how explain but this depend how librairy are develop i think.

Comment: Can you try parsing to UTC time.

Answer (score 0):

I try many things and I think I find I solution to be better performance. Is to use DateTime (JodaTime) and Date librairy. JodaTime to parse text and Date to convert to text.

This is my code and what I try.

```
@Test
public void DateTime() throws ParseException {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime("2018-07-22 00:00:00");
    String formattedDate = dt.toString("dd MMM''yy, HH:mm aa");
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
    System.out.println(formattedDate);

    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse("2018-07-22 00:00:00");
    formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM''yy, HH:mm aa").format(date);
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
    System.out.println(formattedDate);

    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    date = formatter.parseDateTime("2018-07-22 00:00:00").toDate();
    formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM''yy, HH:mm aa").format(date);
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
    System.out.println(formattedDate);
}
```

System.out :

```
545
22 Jul'18, 00:00 AM
16
22 juil.'18, 00:00 AM
0
22 juil.'18, 00:00 AM

Process finished with exit code 0
```

This is why I think JodaTime and Date in test 3 is the better

Comment: Can you see my edited post I have added time for different number of dates.